# Tensorflow quantize_graph cannot import load_quantized_ops_so

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im running Tensorflow compiled from source from the 0.11 release, and am trying to run the quantize graph tool.

Bazel build successfully runs

```
bazel build tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools:quantize_graph
```

but running

```
 bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools/quantize_graph
```

results in

```
File "/Users/vade/Documents/Repositories/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools/quantize_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools/quantize_graph.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.contrib.quantization import load_quantized_ops_so
ImportError: cannot import name load_quantized_ops_so
```

Im not deeply familiar with Tensorflow to know if I have incorrectly installed it, but I'm following instructions on the quantization tutorial on tensorflow.org.

Im running python 2.7.10 if that makes a difference.

Ive tried run bazel clean to no avail, and other tools like optimize_for_inference build and run successfully.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do `import tensorflow as tf` in a python or ipython shell?

Comment: Thanks @Fake - I can indeed import tensorflow in a python shell with no errors.

Comment: I couldn't find `load_quantized_ops_so` in master branch. Try 0.10 (probably with docker)?

Comment: I checkout master and re-compiled a full install after a clean. Appears to work. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

switching to master from 0.11 fixes it apparently!

Comment: We are moving `quantization` from contrib to the core repo.